# How do I convert a string to a verbatim string using its identifier

Tags: c#, verbatim-string

For one method I have the parameters take a string, but I need that string to become a verbatim string once in the method.
Here is an example of what I mean.

```
//the string I have
string test = "c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"

//the string I want
string converted = @"c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"
```

how do I go about converting this using the test identifier?

I have tried:

```
string test = "c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"

string converted = @test;

string converted = @+test;

string converted = @""+test;
```

Is there a way I can do this? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Also, `"c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"` is the equivalent of the text `"c:\documents\testfile\test.txt"`, while `@"c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"` is the equivalent of the text `c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt`. They are not the same string; is that what you want?

Comment: This is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. **Why** do you want to do this?

Comment: The string you have is probably the one you want. Or are you also trying to convert other characters, like `'\t'` (the tab character) to normal strings, like `"\t"` (the `'\'` character followed by the `'t'` character, as a string literal)?

Comment: There is no such thing as a verbatim string *variable*, only a verbatim string *literal*.  A literal is how you define a string value at compile time using source code, and has nothing to do with runtime. So runtime conversion to or from a verbatim string is a meaningless concept; a string is a string.

Comment: `@"c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt"` is equivalent to `"c:\\\\documents\\\\testfile\\\\test.txt"` in verbatim string text are written as it is, and the string notation is the only thing that need to be fixed... for example `"` inside an string should be `""` otherwise it will act as start and the end of string, but when it come twice it work as single `"`

Comment: In addition, I think you may need to create a string to display somewhere as verbatim string. actually that's what I'm looking for too, an encoder and a decoder, but for the file system alone, it would be like this: `converted = "@\"" + test.Replace("\\", "\\\\") + "\""`    or using Interpolated string: `converted = $"@\"{test.Replace("\\", "\\\\")}\""`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the verbatim identifier like you are trying to. You'll have to do something along the lines of:

```
string test = "c:\\documents\\testfile\\test.txt";
string converted = test.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
```